# Increase gap between levels in Graphviz output

Tags: graphviz

Using the following command:

```
dot -Tpng so.dot -o so.png
```

the graphviz code shown produces the (650x255) image further down. I like that there are 3 distinct horizontal levels in the output image, but I'd prefer the difference in height between these 3 levels to be increased; perhaps producing a taller image. Can anyone help?

```
digraph G {
  node [shape="circle"];
  1 -> { 2; 3; 4 }
  2 -> { 5; 6; 7 }
  3 -> { 8; 9; 10 }
  4 -> { 11; 12; 13 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dot -Tpng -Granksep=3.0 so.dot -o so.png
```

which gives

[image]

Documentation: http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/graphviz/html/info/attrs.html#a:ranksep

Comment: Can be written in the code as well, not necessarily passed as an execution parameter: digraph G {ranksep=3; ...